# Swift class omitting brackets with closure: syntactic sugar or something else?

Tags: class, swift, syntax, closures, syntactic-sugar

I'm trying to understand why I can omit the round brackets in a class initialization when it takes a block as parameter.

Example without the brackets:

```
var block = CCActionCallBlock { () -> Void in
    NSLog("sedfjsdkl")
}
```

And here's the formally correct version with brackets:

```
var block = CCActionCallBlock ( { () -> Void in
    NSLog("sedfjsdkl")
})
```

Both variants work as expected, there aren't any runtime errors nor compiler warnings.

Under which circumstances can I omit the class' initializer brackets? Is this the same code or does it have any side-effects? Are there any other syntactic sugars regarding closures/blocks I should be aware of?

*Note:* I'm aware of the fact that a closure as last parameter can be written *after* the brackets, but can't find anything related to omitting the brackets altogether.

For instance I can't just generally omit the class init brackets, it seems to have to take a block/closure as parameter for the syntactic sugar to work:

```
var block = MyClass   // error, obviously ...
```

**Update:**
Apparently Xcode autocompletes to the version without the brackets.

Answer (score 7):

From [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in the Swift reference (emphasis added):

> NOTE
>
> If a closure expression is provided as the function’s **only argument**
>   and you provide that expression as a **trailing closure**, you do **not need**
>   to write a pair of parentheses () after the function’s name when you
>   call the function.

Comment: Note that this is now allowed “if you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the function’s _final_ argument”.