# Syntax Meaning of a Class Name Followed by Curly Brackets in Swift

Tags: swift

Hi I'm a learner of Swift. I'm confused about the *WindowGroup* using in the following syntax. What does it do when we write a class name followed by curly brackets like the *WindowGroup* in following codes?

```
@main
struct MemorizeApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the syntax for closures. In SwiftUI, that's how you make views.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27405122/77567

Comment: This might be helpful for understanding: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/lwpk9f/always_has_been/

Comment: @robmayoff: I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/q/56434549/1187415 would be a better duplicate target.